# Kotlin sortedMap compared by the Pair value not the key

Tags: kotlin

I found this statement

```
sortedMapOf(compareBy<String> { it.length }, Pair("abc", 1), Pair("c", 3), Pair("bd", 4), Pair("bc", 2))
```

So it sorts first by the length of the `key`. However what I need is a sort by the `value` of the map's pairs.

Therefore I tried this:

```
mapOf("eat" to 11.0, "sleep" to 50.0).toSortedMap(Comparator<Pair<String, Double>> { o1, o2 -> o1.second.compareTo(o2.second) })
```

For some reason the part `Comparator<Pair<String, Double>> { o1, o2 -> o1.second.compareTo(o2.second) }` gives me an error.

My IDE (IntelliJ) tells me this:

```
Type mismatch.
Required: Pair<String, Double>
Found: String
```

I don't get it where am I passing a `String`. All I can see is me using the `Pair`.

Answer (score 1):

Key in `mapOf("eat" to 11.0, "sleep" to 50.0)` is of type `String`, hence `toSortedMap` is expecting you to provide a comparator that takes string as argument.

To make the code runnable, you'll have to make a new map where the key is of type `Pair<String, Double>`.

```
mapOf("eat" to 11.0, "sleep" to 50.0)
    .map { Pair(it.key, it.value) to it.value }
    .toMap()
    .toSortedMap { o1, o2 -> o1.second.compareTo(o2.second) }
```

This is of course strange code, but it should answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

`SortedMap`s [are sorted *on their keys*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) - you can't sort them on their values. And here's the signature of `sortedMapOf()`:

```
fun <K, V> sortedMapOf(
    comparator: Comparator<in K>,
    vararg pairs: Pair<K, V>
): SortedMap<K, V>
```

The `comparator` you're passing in *explicitly takes the key's type*, i.e. the `first` value of each `Pair` is getting passed to the comparator, *not* the whole `Pair`.

That's why you're getting the error about `String`s and `Pairs` - you told the `Comparator` that it's getting keys that are `Pair<String, Double>`s, but the `Map` you're passing in has `String` keys and `Double` values (since a `Pair` is treated as a key/value item).

You can't do what you're trying to do, basically! Is there another way to achieve whatever you're doing? A typical approach would be to just use a normal map, and make a sorted list when you need the output:

```
val myMap = mapOf("eat" to 11.0, "sleep" to 50.0)
val sorted = myMap.entries.sortedBy {it.value}
```

Comment: Wow I am kinda confused why it is so unusual to sort a map by values. I'd never think about a use case for the keys.

Comment: @xetra11 the keys are really the primary data in a map - the values are stuff that's associated with the key object. The keys are how you look stuff up, how the map determines whether "this item already exists" etc, and you need to have a (potential) key to do anything with the map! So as far as the actual map goes, it's all about the keys - and that goes for how the keys are ordered too. That sorta goes for the standard `Map` in Kotlin too - it retains the order that *keys* were added. If a key already exists, and you set a new value for it, the key isn't new so it doesn't move

Comment: I will rewrite IT history and make maps all about values! MARK MY WORDS

Comment: @xetra11 hey there's always bi-directional maps! Where you get a view where the values are keys. Not in the Kotlin/Java standard libraries though (e.g. Apache Commons has `BiDiMap` and even a sorted version!) But the issue there is the values need to be unique to work as expected as keys, y'know. But yeah generally you'd do the sorting when you need it (and you can call `toMap` on that code up there and it'll create a new map in the same order as those sorted entries). Having a `SortedMap` that can take values into account would be useful! But it would have to access every item to compare

Comment: ah interesting - thanks for the heads up